# Calling $observe inside link function not working AngularJS (v1.0.8)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        controller: 'myAwesomeCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/myAwesome.html',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('attributeName', function (x) {
                scope.setAttrName(x);
            });
        }
    };
```

Declared inside an ng-repeat and ng-switch:

```
<div ng-repeat="f in fs">
   <div ng-switch on="f.Name">
      <myDirective attribute-name="{{f.AttributeName}}" ng-switch-when="thisIsTrue"></myDirective>
   </div>
</div>
```

And amazingly, it does interpolate {{f.AttributeName}} correctly if I access $attrs from the directive's controller.

```
    $attrs.$observe('attributeName', function (x) {
        $scope.setAttrName(x);  // value of x is 'TheValue'
    });
```

This can't be expected behavior, can it?  v1.0.8

EDIT: I just confirmed it has nothing to do with ng-switch or ng-repeat...  It is not working even if the directive is just by itself.

**HERE IS THE PLUNKER:** http://plnkr.co/edit/p46zuYbFAFCYH394zrUY?p=preview

Comment: Is your directive "terminal"?

Comment: Even if not terminal, the ng-switch-when might be messing things up. Assuming you're on 1.2 RC3? See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4525 which was just fixed today.

Comment: The story on that is, attribute interpolation is a sort of hidden directive, not reflected in the DOM, but still has a priority. It was recently changed from 100 to -100 priority, but just got changed back today.

Comment: I added my version to question.  Thanks for the info, I'll look into it.

Comment: Changing the priority +/-101 doesn't do anything for me.  This is probably a bug related to ng-switch like you suggest.

Comment: @darkporter It's not related to ng-switch.  I added a plunker which demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug, I filed it with the angular team.  I am working on fixing the issue and will submit a pull request.